# What's the best way to get the current URL in Spring MVC?

Tags: url, spring-mvc, httprequest

I'd like to create URLs based on the URL used by the client for the active request. Is there anything smarter than taking the current `HttpServletRequest` object and it's `getParameter...()` methods to rebuilt the complete URL including (and only) it's GET parameters.

**Clarification: If possible I want to resign from using a `HttpServletRequest` object.**

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Well there are two methods to access this data easier, but the interface doesn't offer the possibility to get the whole URL with one call. You have to build it manually:

```
public static String makeUrl(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    return request.getRequestURL().toString() + "?" + request.getQueryString();
}
```

I don't know about a way to do this with any Spring MVC facilities.

If you want to access the current Request without passing it everywhere you will have to add a listener in the web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And then use this to get the request bound to the current Thread:

```
((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest()
```

Comment: Ok, this is a similar approach to what I've done so far. But I'm searching for a way to do this without actually using the `HttpServletRequest` object. This is because I'm using several helper classes / methods and I don't want to pass the request object every time.

Comment: Ok, I know what you mean and added the info you need to access the current request without passing it around.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about the listener. I'm still new to Spring (and Java web development in general). I'm now using your code in combination with Spring Security's `UrlUtils`. Works like a charm.

Comment: In my case it gives the related view path instead of browse url. Any idea about this?

Comment: Without using HttpServletRequest... example in Spring Boot controller methods we don't get this as a parameter... then the other answer of the static call looks good 

ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().toUriString()

Answer (score 115):

Instead of using `RequestContextHolder` directly, you can also use `ServletUriComponentsBuilder` and its static methods:

- `ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()`
- `ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentServletMapping()`
- `ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequestUri()`
- `ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()`

They use `RequestContextHolder` under the hood, but provide additional flexibility to build new URLs using the capabilities of `UriComponentsBuilder`.

Example:

```
ServletUriComponentsBuilder builder = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequestUri();
builder.scheme("https");
builder.replaceQueryParam("someBoolean", false);
URI newUri = builder.build().toUri();
```

Comment: @m4rtin I answered my own question and didn’t want to take the credit for the one who initially helped me solve my problem.

Comment: Also good for Spring 5. I've managed to get the URL inside a `ConstraintValidator` with `ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequestUri().toUriString();`.

Answer (score 19):

Java's URI Class can help you out of this:

```
public static String getCurrentUrl(HttpServletRequest request){
    URL url = new URL(request.getRequestURL().toString());
    String host  = url.getHost();
    String userInfo = url.getUserInfo();
    String scheme = url.getProtocol();
    String port = url.getPort();
    String path = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");
    String query = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.query_string");

    URI uri = new URI(scheme,userInfo,host,port,path,query,null)
    return uri.toString();
}
```

Comment: its giving hostname only

Answer (score 8):

in jsp file:

```
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also add a `UriComponentsBuilder` to the method signature of your controller method. Spring will inject an instance of the builder created from the current request.

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> doSomething(UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder) {
    URI someNewUriBasedOnCurrentRequest = uriComponentsBuilder
            .replacePath(null)
            .replaceQuery(null)
            .pathSegment("some", "new", "path")
            .build().toUri();
  //...
}
```

Using the builder you can directly start creating URIs based on the current request e.g. modify path segments.

See also [UriComponentsBuilderMethodArgumentResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/UriComponentsBuilderMethodArgumentResolver.html)

Comment: Note that the injected `UriComponentsBuilder` does not include the path and query parameters of the request. If you need to access those either use `ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()` or inject an instance of `HttpServletRequest` and use `ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromRequest(request)`

Answer (score 2):

If you need the URL till hostname and not the path use Apache's Common Lib `StringUtil`, and from URL extract the substring till third indexOf `/`.

```
public static String getURL(HttpServletRequest request){
   String fullURL = request.getRequestURL().toString();
   return fullURL.substring(0,StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(fullURL, "/", 3)); 
}
```

**Example:** If *fullURL* is `https://example.com/path/after/url/` then
*Output* will be  `https://example.com`

Answer (score 1):

System.out.println(((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURI());

I used it. hope it's useful.