# How to get URL before redirect to error page?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have been trying to get the URL which was typed wrongly by user before redirection to the custom error page.

Below is what I have but I don't see a way to get the `wrong` URL from the `request` variable

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/errors/404.html")
private String defaultPage(HttpServletRequest request,Exception e){
        request.getRequestURL().toString(); // this prints /error/404.html
        ...
        ...
}
```

I expect to see URL something like `www.example.com/home2` which was keyed in by the user. However when I debug I can see the following

[image]

How do I retrieve the `/home2` from the request ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RequestContextListener to get the request bound to the current Thread.

Check this answer:

[What's the best way to get the current URL in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490821/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-current-url-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: The accepted answer didn't help but the second one did. Thanks for the pointer.