# Java get context url in spring service without HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, spring

In my spring webservice I'm trying to get the url of my application like "http://localhost:8080/mycontext".
My service does not contain any HttpServletRequest var, so I can I get it ?

Comment: You might need to add HttpServletRequest as a parameter. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490821/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-current-url-in-spring-mvc

Comment: `HttpServletRequest` can be injected by Spring in your controller's methods, just add it in the parameters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the current request via the RequestContextHolder like:

```
ServletRequestAttributes sra = (ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
HttpServletRequest req = sra.getRequest();     
req.getContextPath();
req.getPathInfo();
```

Or you can just inject it via Spring into your service:

```
private @Autowired HttpServletRequest request;
```

Comment: Thank you ! I did it with private @Autowired HttpServletRequest request;