# Can a Spring RESTful endpoint know its own URL 'template'

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Once an endpoint is invoked by Sprint/Tomcat, can that endpoint code determine its own URL template? Consider this verb and URL:

```
GET /my_resource/123/
```

The HTTP verb and 'template' looks something like this:

```
GET /my_resource/{id}/
```

I want to send a message to a rabbitMQ exchange, and I want the exchange to be deterministically derivable from the template. For example:

```
get|my_resource.id.
```

(I don't actually know if that's a valid queue. But you can see how I got there.) This allows me to make the endpoints very thin and removes an annoying dependency.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/42650241/1379329 I think?

Comment: Yep, looks like a duplicate as long as I can get the `{id}` portion instead of `123`.

Comment: The request will have an attribute you can get with `request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE)`