# Way to get client url from request object?

Tags: java, spring

I have the following controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("request", request);
        return "error";
    }

}
```

And the following template:

```
URL: <span th:text="${#request.getRequestURL()}">url</span><br/>
```

If I go to the url `http://localhost:8080/this-is-a-404-url`, here is what the template shows:

```
URL: http://localhost:8080/error
```

However, this is not the correct url (it's only the requestMapping). Is there a way to get the client url from the `request` object in the template?

Note, if I had to do this in the controller, I would do: `request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI);`. Is there a way to do that in thymeleaf?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490821/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-current-url-in-spring-mvc) post will solve your problem:

Comment: @Dennis no the issue here is that it's getting "error" instead of "error12232321". "error" is the specified url of the RequestMapping. Does that make sense?

Comment: @David542 no it does not. Your template seems to indicate that you want to have the `url` and the `method`? In any case both are easily attainable from the request.

Comment: @Aris please see updated question. I've tried to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the above by getting the forwarded request uri:

```
URL: <span th:text="${#request.getAttribute('javax.servlet.forward.request_uri')}">url</span><br/>
```

This will return your "/this-is-a-404-url"